# How does one constrain a shape using draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

When using the ellipse, circle or rectangle tool using most drawing apps, holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> or other control key will constrain the shapes aspect ratio. For example, a circle will remain circular or a rectangle will remain a square.

I cannot get this to happen using draw.io, so am forced to use the snap to grid to create perfect circles or squares.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to constrain a shape during the drawing process?

Answer (score 2):

The underlying library does have this, we just never assigned it to a key. We've switched it on now and assigned it to the <kbd>shift</kbd> key.